# How to freeze an area in Excel?

Tags: excel

I want to freeze only certain cells in an area in an excel sheet to make that area act like a fixed menu. A screenshot is attached as an example. The highlighted area needs to be fixed when a user scrolls vertically.

Thanks for any advice.

[image: Demo Image]

Answer (score 2):

Excel has a "Freeze panes" for this, in the "View" menu, "Window" item, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

You select the cell at the right bottom of the area you want to freeze and you do "freeze panes". There are some more possibilities you can find while clicking "Help" and searching for "freeze".

**edit after edit of original question:**
Oh. Seeing the edit, I think I believe what you want: you want the left columns to be fixed (you can't scroll down) while you want the other columns to be scrollable. This is not possible, because it would mean that the number of your row does not correspond with the row number of the cell you're in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what I want is to freeze Column A-C when I scroll vertically. The freeze pane function can freeze column A-C when I scroll horizontally.

Comment: I'm not sure if we understand each other: imagine you click in cell "D10". When you scroll to the right, the column "A:C" will be fixed. When you scroll down, the rows "1:10" will be fixed. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Hi Dominique, thanks again. I changed the screenshot in my original answer to make it clearer. It's like fixing only part of rows, not the entire row.

Comment: @Juneyee: now I understand. I've explained why's it's not possible.